# Executing shell script in ubuntu

Tags: linux, shell, unix

Maybe I am missing something here but I have the following small bash script to delete some old files that get created when using flex and yacc its pretty simple but when I run the script it echos the result to the terminal but does not delete the file I'm probably missing something stupid could you guys point me in the right direction.

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "rm -f y.tab.h"; (just using one file for now)
```

I tried changing it to

```
echo rm -f y.tab.h;
```

but still no luck

I tried executing it with bash delete.sh and sh delete.sh and even using chmod +x on the file and executing it with ./

Answer (score 2):

Remove echo statement

Just use

```
rm -f y.tab.h
```